# What was going on with Grindelwald's tongue?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

When held in prison, Grindelwald seems unable to speak and Seraphina Picquery explains that they have taken out his tongue.

Later when in transit to be tried in Europe, Grindelwald's escort taunts him with the words:

> **Spielman:** No more silver tongue, eh?

Later still, Grindelwald seems to have a forked tongue(!) and speaks without difficulty.

What did I miss - how did Grindelwald get his tongue back?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Grindelwald's tongue was never removed

Yes Picquery says that they have removed his tongue due to him being very persuasive.

> **PICQUERY** It was necessary. He’s extremely powerful. We’ve had to change his guard three times—he’s very... persuasive. So we removed his tongue.
>
> <sub>*Fantasitc Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 3</sub>

However, as we find out during the escape Grindelwald had already traded places with Abernathy and they have both used Polyjuice Potion to look like each other.

> **SCENE 7**
>
> [...]
>
> **SPIELMAN** No more silver tongue, eh?
>
> *But GRINDELWALD is transforming...*
>
> **SCENE 8**
>
> **EXT. THESTRAL-DRAWN CARRIAGE—NIGHT**
>
> *ABERNATHY adjusts his grip underneath the carriage. His face too is changing. His hair is turning blond and lengthening... he is GRINDELWALD. He raises the Elder Wand.*
>
> **SCENE 9**
>
> **INT. THESTRAL-DRAWN CARRIAGE—NIGHT**
>
> *GRINDELWALD’S rapid transformation into a tongueless ABERNATHY is almost complete.*
>
> **SPIELMAN** *(shocked)* Oh!
>
> <sub>*Fantasitc Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*</sub>

Once the escape is all but complete Grindelwald then casts a spell to create a new tongue for Abernathy.

> **SCENE 15**
>
> **INT. THESTRAL-DRAWN CARRIAGE—NIGHT**
>
> *GRINDELWALD appears at the door and nods to ABERNATHY. He throws the door open so the water pours out—along with the two remaining AURORS. GRINDELWALD clambers inside and retrieves the vial from ABERNATHY’S mouth by the chain, casting a spell that grants ABERNATHY a new forked tongue.*
>
> <sub>*Fantasitc Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*</sub>

Comment: +1 Expert-level answer, with evidence. Well done and many thanks.

Comment: If a tongue was that easy to recreate, what was the point of removing it?

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach cos he had no way of recreating it whilst in the cell.

Comment: So, Grindelwald was impersonating Abernathy a long time ago, right?